# i915 errors after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, i915

I had Intel Graphics installed on 14.04, and since upgrading to 16.04 I get frequent error messages on booting or updating. I've attached a screenshot.[image]

It's clearly something to do with the old Intel Graphics Installer. Can I remove it safely? Is there a ppa I should remove?

Edit: In response to the comment below, lscpi | grep VGA returns:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core
>   processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

The screenshot is here:
[image]

Comment: Could you add the output of `lcpi | grep VGA` and a screenshot of what the UI `Software & Updates` shows on the `Additional drivers` tab?